# Google Places API: different output for textsearch and nearbysearch (formatted_address missing)

Tags: google-places-api

Want to use Google Places API nearby search for reverse lookup using coordinates.

I use [nearbysearch](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) endpoint.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.892674%2C151.200727&rankby=distance&type=bar&key=...
```

What is missing is `formatted_address`.

When trying to use [textsearch](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) instead, I **do** get `formatted_address`.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-33.892674%2C151.200727&rankby=distance&type=bar&key=...
```

Both return the same first place_id and look very similar.
Differences I noticed:

- textsearch: formatted_address, empty opening_hours are included
- nearbysearch: vicinity, scope, empty opening_hours are not included

**How do I get formatted_address?**

**Update**: I checked and both types should return the [same fields](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields#places-api-fields-support).

---

details

When searching by distance & type I guess I could use either `nearbysearch` or `textsearch`, but when searching by prominence I will have to use `nearbysearch` as `textsearch` requires either `type` or `query`.

The query I would like to use (using nearbysearch, so missing formatted_address):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.892674%2C151.200727&rankby=prominence&radius=500&key=...
```

Full output `textsearch`

```
    {
      "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
      "formatted_address": "7 Cope St, Redfern NSW 2016",
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": -33.892682,
          "lng": 151.20075
        },
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": -33.89147812010727,
            "lng": 151.2019769298927
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": -33.89417777989272,
            "lng": 151.1992772701072
          }
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
      "id": "d8b3f319ad00fafd66527b248e450284a53386c2",
      "name": "Arcadia",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true
      },
      "photos": [
        {
          "height": 3000,
          "html_attributions": [
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100984405419723237513\">Colin Hannah</a>"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAvnYeIFoCoiiQoyRqKQqpz1yJK71eXM3wYuCiTFTTtj3iwTiIW_z865AfLogqMiEyyBh5GqZoxAcHDmzyE8KelhGEh3C-ggm5LQDGK4zFWxdTNCholvXurq0ce7zLoztgEhBgklqzYxK5jhDhwqB5wuabGhQRUb448z5zV9l7EDSmXLMo5icv1w",
          "width": 4000
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "ChIJ3Y3vQdqxEmsRTvCcbZnsYJ8",
      "plus_code": {
        "compound_code": "4642+W7 Redfern, New South Wales",
        "global_code": "4RRH4642+W7"
      },
      "price_level": 2,
      "rating": 4.5,
      "reference": "ChIJ3Y3vQdqxEmsRTvCcbZnsYJ8",
      "types": [
        "bar",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "user_ratings_total": 279
    },
```

Full output `nearbysearch`:

```
    {
      "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": -33.892682,
          "lng": 151.20075
        },
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": -33.8914789697085,
            "lng": 151.2019760802915
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": -33.89417693029149,
            "lng": 151.1992781197085
          }
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
      "id": "d8b3f319ad00fafd66527b248e450284a53386c2",
      "name": "Arcadia",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true
      },
      "photos": [
        {
          "height": 3024,
          "html_attributions": [
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101220276595662877555\">Milan</a>"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAA7u4ZpZOddZ8ypuGySsQ1lG0HEX4Ke0DHeYtHYN1gEchx-yf1U-DVLNHVdmFVLoocHbMmWlMVCqcW9oMnpDC4-dw6ObZAovVQG90GpVD3sYeMEpzBB80yjhttjZ1lsIEdEhCzQJane_k8xy-HlI9ZlE9WGhQJ13KgR88Q239e8ocBCt5H0BgpKQ",
          "width": 4032
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "ChIJ3Y3vQdqxEmsRTvCcbZnsYJ8",
      "plus_code": {
        "compound_code": "4642+W7 Redfern NSW, Australia",
        "global_code": "4RRH4642+W7"
      },
      "price_level": 2,
      "rating": 4.5,
      "reference": "ChIJ3Y3vQdqxEmsRTvCcbZnsYJ8",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",   <===========
      "types": [
        "bar",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "user_ratings_total": 279,
      "vicinity": "7 Cope Street, Redfern"   <===========
    },
```

Comment: I read in the docs: *The following example shows a Nearby Search response. A Text Search response is similar, except that it returns a `formatted_address` instead of a `vicinity` property.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from @MrUpsidown points to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses) where it is stated:

> A Text Search response is similar, except that it returns a `formatted_address` instead of a `vicinity` property

So, it seems that's just the way it is.

```
  "formatted_address": "7 Cope St, Redfern NSW 2016",
```

vs

```
  "vicinity": "7 Cope Street, Redfern"
```

Comment: I don't think this is completly right. I have tested with some locations, and the response on the field "vicinity" is only the city without any other information.